# List home directory without absolute path

Tags: python

I'm having problem with listing home directory of current user without knowing absolute path to it. I've tried with the following, but it doesn't work:

```
[root@blackbox source]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:38:36)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir('/root')
['python', '.bashrc', '.viminfo']
>>> os.listdir('~')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~'
>>>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use the [`os.path.expanduser()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.expanduser('~')
'/home/username'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could ask the Operation System like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['HOME']
'/home/noctua'
>>> os.listdir(os.environ['HOME'])
```

Comment: The `os.path.expanduser()` function will work even when `HOME` has not been set (on Windows, for example).

Comment: Indeed, once again, I forgot there are still people using windows.